# UICollectionView + UIRefreshControl animation differences to Apple Mail app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

I am implementing a ViewController with an `UICollectionView` + `UIRefreshControl` and large titles. Its pull to refresh animation looks different compared to the ones from Apple Apps like Mail.

In the mail app the `UIActivityIndicator` is somehow "building up" based on how far the user has dragged, whereas in my sample implementation the indicator is fading in. I already tried to play with the top anchors or different ways to trigger the refresh but I cannot get the "native" animation of the `UIRefreshControl`. At the following link, 2 videos are shown, one showing the mail app animation, the other one my custom view implementations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbMt4.jpg

Are there any hidden configurations or maybe some other ways to implement this "native" animation.
What I don't know though is whether the Apple mail app is using an `UICollectionView`. I also tried it with a UITableView and was also facing the "fading in" animation rather than this "growing" animation.

Maybe someone already had experienced this and knows what could be the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is the code of the View Controller that is creating the UICollectionView. It also contains some references to a ViewModel and some custom types, but these should not interfere with the UI differences I see.

```
class CollectionViewTestViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - UI Properties
    private lazy var collectionView = makeCollectionView()
    private lazy var dataSource = makeDataSource()

    private(set) lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addAction(
                UIAction { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.viewModel.refresh()
                }, for: .valueChanged
        )
        return refreshControl
    }()

    // MARK: - ViewModel
    private let viewModel: CollectionViewTestViewModel

    // MARK: - Combine
    private let cancelBag = CancelBag()

    // MARK: - Initializer
    init(viewModel: CollectionViewTestViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.title = "CollectionView"
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Lifecylce
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.configureUI()
        self.bindToViewModel()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Setup
extension CollectionViewTestViewController {

    private func configureUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - Collection View Handling
extension CollectionViewTestViewController {

    // MARK: - UICollectionView
    func makeCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
        let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
        let view =  UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.refreshControl = refreshControl
        view.contentInset = .init(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        return view
    }


    // MARK: - Cell Registration
    func makeCellRegistration() -> UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Contact> {
        UICollectionView.CellRegistration { cell, indexPath, contact in
            // Configuring each cell's content:
            var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            config.text = contact.name
            config.secondaryText = "\(contact.birthday)"
            cell.contentConfiguration = config

            // Showing a disclosure indicator as the cell's accessory:
            cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator()]
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Data Source
    func makeDataSource() -> UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Contact> {
        let cellRegistration = makeCellRegistration()

        return UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Contact>(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: { view, indexPath, item in
                view.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                    using: cellRegistration,
                    for: indexPath,
                    item: item
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

// MARK: - MVVM
extension CollectionViewTestViewController {
    private func bindToViewModel() {
        self.viewModel.$contacts
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] sections in
                switch sections {
                case .initial:
                    break
                case .loading:
                    self?.collectionView.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
                case let .value(data):
                    self?.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    self?.updateList(with: data)
                case let .error(error):
                    self?.collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
            .store(in: self.cancelBag)
    }
}

// MARK: - Data Updating
extension CollectionViewTestViewController {
    func updateList(with data: [Contact]) {
           var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Contact>()
           snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)
           snapshot.appendItems(data, toSection: .all)
           dataSource.apply(snapshot)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work with top anchors. The "growing" animation is a result of the `valueChanged` event of `UIRefreshControl`. Add a target to your `UIRefreshControl` and set it to your `UICollectionView` like this:

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

And for the "refresh" function:

```
@objc func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
   // End refreshing at some point
   self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing your answer. Unfortunately this code does not change the behaviour for me. I also posted my current code in the question now, maybe this helps somehow

Comment: I've tried using your code without the ViewModel references and I still get the expected growing animation. Maybe the issue is due to the calls to `beginRefreshing` and `endRefreshing` in your `bindToViewModel` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for actually testing that. I just tried several things and very interestingly. Even with keeping the view model and the `bindToViewModel ` as is, when the ViewController is not part of a `UINavigationController` I get the growing animation. But as soon as it is part of a navigation stack the growing animation is gone

Comment: You're absolutely right. I tried the code with a `UINavigationController` and the issue occurs. I also noticed that this only happens if `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` is set to `true`. When set to `false` I get the expected growing animation.

Comment: Oh right, with "small" titles, it is working. Then I wonder what Apple is doing in the mail app. Maybe there are not using the `prefersLargeTitles` property at all

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, after further testing I found that calling `configureUI()` in `viewDidAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()` fixed the animation issue. Maybe you can give it a try and if it works, I will update my answer.